# Convert an array of simple arrays into an array of Associative arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using PHP for this and I'm using the array listed here:
https://gist.github.com/aghouseh/3926213

So basically it's an array with State name, and within those state names is a list of counties, something like this:

```
$counties = array(
"Alabama" => array(
    "Autauga County",
    "Baldwin County",
    "Barbour County",
    "Bibb County")
"California => array(
    "Los angeles County",
    "San francisco county"));
```

So basically what I'm trying to accomplish is this:

```
$counties = array(
"Alabama" => array(
    "Autauga County" => "Autauga County",
    "Baldwin County" => "Baldwin County",
    "Barbour County" => "Barbour County",
    "Bibb County" => "Bibb County")
"California => array(
    "Los angeles County" => "Los angeles County",
    "San francisco county" => "San francisco county"));
```

I wanna make that second level array into an associative array.
I tried to search for an answer and I came up with this but didn't work:

```
foreach ($counties as $state) {
        foreach ($state as $county) {
            array_combine($county, $county);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new array as you wish and replace the original with it:

```
foreach ($counties as $state => $x) {
    $c = array();
    foreach ($x as $county) {
        $c[$county] = $county;
    }
    $counties[$state] = $c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually `array_combine` would be a fine and elegant way to do this. If only you used it at the right level and stored its result somewhere! Note that `array_combine` doesn't work by reference on the original array. It returns the result instead. Use this:

```
foreach($counties as &$states) {
    $states = array_combine($states, $states);
}
```

That's all the code you need to get this done.